# Troubles passing arguments through execlp function - C

Tags: c, fork

i'm using a given md5 function who calculates a file hash when you feed it with a file address. Thing is that i need to execute this program using fork() and then load it using any exe...() function(im trying with execlp()) but when i do it and i pass the single argument i need to calculate the hash it fails. I tried running md5 program manually with the exact argument i use in execlp and it doesn't fail so i'm just assuming it must be something wrong with execlp parameters. Here's an example i made to explain the scenario:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
  pid_t cpid;int status;
  cpid = fork();
  if(cpid < 0){
    printf("Error fork\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }else if (!cpid){
        if (execlp("./hashMD5/me/md5","md5","testfile.a",(char*)NULL) == -1){
          printf("Error: Loading process\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
  }else{
    waitpid(cpid,&status,0);
  }
    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

when i use this i got an error in terminal:

`$testfile.a can't be opened`

but if i manually execute the md5 program with the exactly same argument i got the correct execution.

What's wrong? Help!

Comment: Good: casting `NULL` in `execlp`. Bad: casting the return value of `malloc`. Neutral: `sizeof (char)` doesn't exactly change...

Comment: BTW how come your pathaux can be `testfile.a` *after* the `strcat`?!

Comment: there is no meaning of writing printf statement after execlp, it won't prints  because execlp will replace whole child/parent process with md5 process

Comment: You have apparently made no attempt to debug this yourself. There is no [mcve], and you don't check *why* your operations fail (if they fail).

Comment: Did you remember to remove the newline at the end of the name read from the input?

Comment: I've been trying to debug this myself about an hour and a half, otherwise i wouldn't have come to here if that was not the case.

Comment: Then post your [mcve].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala pathaux won't look like "testfile.a", was just an example. it will look more like "../../adirectory/testfile.a" that's just bc i saved the executable i need inside folders in main program directory. i Don't get why you say  casting the return value of malloc. Can you explain further please?

Comment: Good call, @JonathanLeffler. Let me check that out

Comment: @FrankPonte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @achal it is there in the branch that is executed **if** execlp fails

Comment: New thing i learned! thanks! btw im gonna edit the code to a simple one and meavy can be a " Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"

Comment: Is the edited code still failing?

Comment: Yes, i edited bc might be easier to understand.. But it still failing! @alk

Comment: Neither of these issues is directly a cause of your troubles, but … Note that because there are slashes in the path name given for the command (not function) `"./hashMD5/me/md5"`, you might as well use `execl()` as `execlp()` — `execlp()` will never use the path setting because the name contains slashes.  You should also report error messages on standard error (`stderr`), not standard output.  Also, there's no need to test the return status of `execlp()`; if it returns, it failed (and if it succeeds, it never returns).

Comment: For debugging, I recommend capturing the return value from `waitpid()` and printing that and the status returned — use `0x%.4X` or similar to print the status readably.

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. documents why each header file is included
3. uses a proper call to `execl()` rather than `execlp()` because `execl()` expects the first parameter to be a complete path while `execlp()` expects the first parameter to be just a file name.
4. properly formats the code, for ease of readability and understanding
5. properly handles calling `execl()` and possible failure of that call
6. properly passes error messages to `stderr` rather than `stdout`, using `perror()`, so the reason the system thinks the error occurred is also displayed on `stderr`.

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <unistd.h>   // fork(), execlp()
#include <sys/wait.h> // waitpid()

int main( void )
{
    pid_t cpid;int status;
    cpid = fork();

    if(cpid < 0)
    { // error
        perror("Error fork\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else if (!cpid)
    { // child
        execl("./hashMD5/me/md5","md5","testfile.a", NULL);

        perror("Error: Loading process\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else
    { // parent
        waitpid(cpid,&status,0);
    }

    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't document why `<sys/types.h>` is included.  POSIX 2004 did away with the need to include `<sys/types.h>` explicitly (though it was theoretically needed in POSIX 1997).  Also note that in theory, you should cast the `NULL` to `(char *)NULL`.  Whether you get away without the cast depends on the definition of `NULL`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  the final `NULL` parameter can also be left off the call.  The `sys/types.h` header file is included because some (older) C support headers failed to include it in their definition.   Since it is not directly related to any objects in the OPs code, there is no clear reason for its inclusion.  However, we have no guarantee that everyone is using an up-to-date compiler.  Especially if using Visual Studio or Visual C.

Comment: No; the NULL cannot be left off the calls to `execl*()` functions. It marks the end of the argument list and is crucial, and must be a null character pointer, which is why the cast is necessary on some machines (e.g. a 64-bit system where `#define NULL 0` is used instead of `#define NULL ((void *)0)`).  And I documented that older means 'archaic' as in "prior to POSIX 2004", which is itself very old these days.  You claim to have documented why each header is included; you didn't annotate why `<sys/types.h>` was included.  It's up to you; you can include it and add a commentary about why, or …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  Here are the prototypes for `execl()` and `execlp()`, from the linux MAN page for those functions:  `int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);
       int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);`  Which clearly indicates the NULL argument is optional

Comment: No; it clearly indicates that the NULL argument is mandatory, but cannot be specified as mandatory using the `...` notation because that says "all bets are off about what goes here".

Comment: Note that the POSIX description of [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) includes: _`int execl(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);`_ and _The arguments represented by `arg0,...` are pointers to null-terminated character strings. These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. **The list is terminated by a null pointer.** The argument `arg0` should point to a filename string that is associated with the process being started by one of the `exec` functions_ (emphasis added).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I appreciate the improvements people gave me, i'm always happy to learn new things!

The problem was with the argument itself: Even when you use execlp to create a brand new process **the path of the argument remains relative to parent process**, that's why was not working. After several headaches i finally realized that. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You mean that the `testfile.a` file was in the `hashMD5/me` directory, not in the directory containing that path?  Yes, all relative paths are interpreted relative to the current directory of the process, which is the current directory of the parent process unless the program does an exlicit `chdir()` operation to change directory.

Comment: exactly, @JonathanLeffler. Oh, im gonna read about that function, awesome!